# How to create a nested dictionary from a single dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looking for a nice pythonic solution for my problem.
I have a dictionary like:

```
char_dist = {'b' : 0.345, 'd' : 0.158, 'c' : 0.059, 'w' : 0.437}
```

And I would like to get some like this:

```py
new_dict = {'b': {'b': 0.11902,
                  'd': 0.05451,
                  'c': 0.020355,
                  'w': 0.150765},
            'd': {'b': 0.054501,
                  'd': 0.024964,
                  'c': 0.009322,
                  'w': 0.150765},
            'c': {'b': 0.020355,
                  'd': 0.009322,
                  'c': 0.003481,
                  'w': 0.025783},
            'w': {'b': 0.150765,
                  'd': 0.069046,
                  'c': 0.025783,
                  'w': 0.190969}}
```

The new dict is the result of multiply the values from old dict.

```
new_dict = {char_dist[key] : {char_dist[key1]: char_dist[key1][value] * char_dist[key2][value], etc...
```

P.S. I tried some like this, but still figuring out:

```
new = defaultdict(dict)

for base, val in char_distribution.items():
    new[base] = {base: p for base, p in
                     zip('bdcw', char_dist)}


pprint(matrix)
```

But I got the same value for all the nested dictionary:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
            {'b': {'b': 0.11902,
              'd': 0.05451,
              'c': 0.020355,
              'w': 0.150765},
             'c': {'b': 0.11902,
              'd': 0.05451,
              'c': 0.020355,
              'w': 0.150765}
            'd': {'b': 0.11902,
              'd': 0.05451,
              'c': 0.020355,
              'w': 0.150765}
             'w': {'b': 0.11902,
              'd': 0.05451,
              'c': 0.020355,
              'w': 0.150765}})
```

I want to create a kind of transition matrix.

Comment: Do you really need that? What can you do with that which you can't do with the original? Also, your desired result is invalid.

Comment: you are getting same values because of this `zip('bdcw', char_dist)`

Comment: Looks like `{kk:{k: vv*v for k, v in char_dist.items()} for kk, vv in char_dist.items()}` would do it, but I don't see the point.

Comment: It is a transition matrix representing the probabilities from w -> d, w->c etc.

Comment: Yeah, you need to do a nested loop over the items as @alaniwi showed, but to me I think this sacrifices a lot of memory for a little bit of speed. If you have the keys `x` and `y`, then to get what you want it is simply `d[x]*d[y]` which is constant time. You are essentially caching that operation but using a lot of extra space

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sounds like you should be adding an answer also then...

Comment: Ok . I will try the nested loop to check. But I really appreciate your tips. Thank you all

Comment: BTW I think the value of `new_dict['d']['w']` in the question is wrong (looks like a copy and paste that didn't get edited) -- aside from the various commas that should be decimal points -- but we get the general idea of what it's meant to contain.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with nested dictionary comprehensions:

```py
expected = {kk: {k: vv*v for k, v in char_dist.items()} for kk, vv in char_dist.items()}

print(expected)
[out]:
{'b': {'b': 0.11902, 'c': 0.02035, 'd': 0.05451, 'w': 0.15076},
 'c': {'b': 0.02035, 'c': 0.00348, 'd': 0.00932, 'w': 0.02578},
 'd': {'b': 0.05451, 'c': 0.00932, 'd': 0.02496, 'w': 0.06905},
 'w': {'b': 0.15076, 'c': 0.02578, 'd': 0.06905, 'w': 0.19097}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you're dealing with distributions, some linear algebra won't hurt. Meet Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
....
df = pd.DataFrame([char_dist])
df.T.dot(df)
```

Output:

```
          b         d         c         w
b  0.119025  0.054510  0.020355  0.150765
d  0.054510  0.024964  0.009322  0.069046
c  0.020355  0.009322  0.003481  0.025783
w  0.150765  0.069046  0.025783  0.190969
```

Comment: I not using pandas right now. Just pure python. Thank you. (I like pandas alot).

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest:

```
char_dist = {'b': 0.345, 'd': 0.158, 'c': 0.059, 'w': 0.437}
old_dict = {'b': 0.68746258423, 'd': 0.5429823052, 'c': 0.5849805243, 'w': 0.95840285}

new_dict = dict.fromkeys(char_dist, old_dict)

print(new_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Came up with something like this.

```
base_distribution = {'A' : 0.345, 'C' : 0.158, 'G' : 0.059, 'T' : 0.437}

markov = defaultdict()
for base, val in base_distribution.items():
    markov[base] = markov.get(base, {})
    for key, val in base_distribution.items():
        p = round(base_distribution[base] * base_distribution[key], 4)
        markov[base][key] = markov[base].get(key, p)
pprint(markov)

defaultdict(None,
            {'A': {'A': 0.119, 'C': 0.0545, 'G': 0.0204, 'T': 0.1508},
             'C': {'A': 0.0545, 'C': 0.025, 'G': 0.0093, 'T': 0.069},
             'G': {'A': 0.0204, 'C': 0.0093, 'G': 0.0035, 'T': 0.0258},
             'T': {'A': 0.1508, 'C': 0.069, 'G': 0.0258, 'T': 0.191}})
```